# Why is smallness of $\cal A$ important in definition of category $\cal B^A$ of functors?

Tags: category-theory

Let $\cal A$ be a small category, $\cal B$ be arbitrary category, and $\cal B^A$ be a category whose objects are functors $\cal A\rightarrow B$ and morphisms are natural transformations of these functors. Why is smallness of $\cal A$ important?

I am a little bit confused by this question. Do you know the answer?

Comment: Intuitively, an object $F$ in $\mathcal{B}^\mathcal{A}$ is **at least as big as** $\mathcal{A}$ itself: $F$ has to contain a "bit" for each object (and morphism, for that matter) of $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, Do you mean that if $\cal A$ isn't small it's possible to build two functors $F,G:\cal A\rightarrow B$ such that $\cal{B}^\cal{A}$ $(F,G)$ is not a set?

Comment: Even worse than that: no **single** functor $F:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\mathcal{B}$ will be a set if $\mathcal{A}$ is large. So it's not that the hom-"sets" of $\mathcal{B}^\mathcal{A}$ are too big, but **each individual** object *(and each individual morphism for that matter)* of $\mathcal{B^A}$ is too big. Contrast this with something like the surreal numbers, where the whole structure is "big" (= proper class sized) but each element in it (= each surreal number) is "small" (= is, or is represented by, a set).

Comment: @MaximNikitin -- think about how you would specify $F$. Remember that, formally, we identify a function $f : A \to B$ with the set of ordered pairs $\{ (a,f(a) \mid a \in A \}$. Well we run a similar encoding with functors, but now $F : \mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{B}$ is identified with the union of the class of pairs $\{ (A, FA) \mid A \in \mathcal{A} \}$ and the class of pairs $\{ (f, Ff) \mid f : A \to B \in \mathcal{A} \}$. In the case $\mathcal{A}$ is large, it's easy to see that this means $F$ is encoded by a proper class, which is a potential problem

Comment: See:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4339166/a-category-of-functors?noredirect=1#comment9050508_4339166